# Show that the map $T(x)=x+a \sin^2( \pi x)$ is uniquely ergodic on the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The task is to prove that the map $T(x)=x+a \sin^2( \pi x)$ on the unit circle is uniquely ergodic for $a < \frac{1}{\pi}$.  I tried to show that Birkhoff sums of the characters with respect to $T: S^1 \to S^1$ all converge uniformly to a constant, but I don't think that will work.

Comment: Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4133544/169085.

Comment: Thank you, but this is on the circle and the link is for the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Succinctly, your idea does work.

For posterity, this is (part of) Exr.4.7.3 in Brin & Stuck's *Introduction to Dynamical Systems* (p.90).

Here is a humble graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tgrhizoot6. It's also useful to have the phase portrait in mind; it looks like  this:

[image]

(I've taken this image from Hasselblatt & Katok's *A First Course in Dynamics*, p.130. Note the resemblance to the projective action of shear matrices; indeed horocycle flows are also uniquely ergodic and unique ergodicity is a topological property (see [Topological Invariance of Unique Ergodicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149155/169085) for the latter statement).)

---

For a fixed $a\in]0,1/\pi[$, put $T=T_a: \mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{T}, x\mapsto x+a\sin^2(\pi x)$. Note that $T$ has a unique fixed point $0\in\mathbb{T}$, so that $\delta_0$ is an invariant Borel probability measure. Thus to show that $T$ is uniquely ergodic it suffices to show that for any continuous $\phi:\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{R}$ and for any $x\in \mathbb{T}$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi\circ T^k(x)=\phi(0).$$

Since $0$ is a fixed point we may assume $x\in\mathbb{T}\setminus0$. Also note that pointwise convergence is sufficient; uniform convergence will be automatic (see e.g. Einsiedler & Ward's *Ergodic Theory with a view toward Number Theory*, Thm.4.10 on p.105). Let us lift everything to the unit interval $[0,1]$ without changing notation.

Observe that $0< x < T(x) < T^2(x) < \cdots < T^n(x) < \cdots < 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n(x)=1$. Fix $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Then since $\phi$ is uniformly continuous, for some $\delta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ if $y$ and $z$ are $\delta$-close then $\phi(y)$ and $\phi(z)$ are $\epsilon$-close. There is an $N\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq N}$ we have $|T^n(x)-1|<\delta$; thus

$$\exists N\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0},\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq N}: |\phi\circ T^n(x)-\phi(1)|<\epsilon.$$

Then we have, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq N}$,

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{0\leq k<n}\phi\circ T^k(x) -\phi(1)\right|
&\leq \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{0\leq k<n}\left|\phi\circ T^k(x) -\phi(1)\right|\\
&= \dfrac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{0\leq k<N}\left|\phi\circ T^k(x) -\phi(1)\right|+\sum_{N\leq k<n}\left|\phi\circ T^k(x) -\phi(1)\right|\right)\\
&\leq \dfrac{1}{n}(N2|\phi|_{C^0}+ (n-N)\epsilon)
= \epsilon + \dfrac{N(2|\phi|_{C^0}-\epsilon)}{n}.
\end{align*}

Taking $n\to\infty$ we are done since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary. (Note that $1\sim0$ when we project back down to the circle.)

Comment: Thank you.  I also thought to say that the set of non-wandering points has to have measure 1 for any invariant probability measure.  The idea then is to show that the fixed point is the only point that is non-wandering and we have the result.  This is basically the proof for that as well.

Comment: Also, I've read through Karl Petersen's and Peter Walter's ergodic theory books and now I'm looking at Brin and Stuck.  Do you recommend any other books that might supplement these?  I also need to start learning smooth and hyperbolic dynamics so if you know any good references for those it would be appreciated.

Comment: Mañé's book would be worth taking a look (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2577239/169085). Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959120/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2106868/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510291/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/721127/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244323/169085,https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445925/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46889/169085.

Comment: Barreira's books (with coauthors typically) are also worthwhile overall in my opinion. There are also books about "beyond hyperbolicity", that generalize hyperbolicity in different directions. Overall I think it is more efficient to chase references in papers as needed.

Comment: Finally Anosov's memoir "Geodesic Flows On Closed Riemannian Manifolds With Negative Curvature" is still relevant, readable, and instructive in my opinion.

Comment: (I also have an opinion on whose books should be avoided of course, but strategically I will keep this to myself.)